# Counter Update Alters list of Counter objects Python

Tags: python, counter

So this seems pretty odd but suppose you have a list of counters (say for 5 different files). Apparently using update on a separate declaration of one of the Counter objects will alter the original Counter in the list. Anyone know why?

```
from collections import Counter

counts = [Counter({'A':5,'B':0,'C':10}),Counter({'A':2,'B':0,'C':0}), Counter({'A':2,'B':0,'C':6}),Counter({'A':5,'B':0,'C':6}),Counter({'A':5,'B':0,'C':6})]

def combine_counts(counts):
    comb = counts[0]
    for c in counts[1:]:
        comb.update(c)
    return comb

comb = combine_counts(counts)
print comb
print counts
```

Now look at counts and you will find comb has the correct counts, but it has altered counts[0]. Even though counts[0] should not have been changed in my understanding?

anyway it was an easy fix:

```
def combine_counts(counts):
    comb = Counter({})
    for c in counts:
        comb.update(c)
    return comb
```

Can anyone answer why the first one changed the list element?

Comment: Like the dictionary they're based on, Counters are mutable. **Assignment is not copying**. `comb = counts[0]` just points that name at the first element in the list, see http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: In your implementation, `comb` becomes simply shorthand for `counts[0]`. Your best bet would be to create an empty counter, and update it iteratively with each of the counters in the list

Comment: Your first code would need `comb = counts[0].copy()` as you just have a reference to the dict in the list not a copy of the dict.